# Privacy preserving aggregation of encrypted data

Tags: encryption, public-key, homomorphic-encryption, threshold-cryptography

I have the following problem: I have $t$ servers $S_1, S_2, S_3, \ldots, S_t$, each of them storing some $key : value$ list. They have to upload this data into a big dropbox server $D$, but in such a way that $D$ doesn't know which $key:value$ pair comes from which $S_i$. My idea was that each $S_i$ would encrypt its list into $c_i$, and then upload it to $D$. Once $D$ obtained all $c_i$ from each $S_i$ it would aggregate all of them into $c = Aggr(c_1, c_2, \ldots c_t)$. Once the aggregation is finished, $D$ would be able to decrypt $c$ using some threshold-key decryption. In general, the security requirements would be: $D$ can decrypt only the aggregated data, not any of the partial $c_i$. That should hold even if some of the servers are malicious and would like to help $D$ decrypt any of the single $c_i$.
Would it be possible to construct such a schema? If yes, can someone point me to some literature which can guide me?

Comment: Can you define aggregate?

Comment: @levgeni I mean just simple concatenation, i.e., if $c_1 = Enc(l_1), c_2 = Enc(l_2), \ldots c_k = Enc(l_k)$, where $l_i$ is a list of $key:value$ pairs, then $Dec(c) = l_1 || l_2 || l_3 || \ldots l_k$.

Comment: Just a follow-up - actually it would be required that Dec(c) gives concatenation of all $l_i$ but in a randomized order, i.e, Dec(c) does not allow to link a plaintext $l_i$ to a server which sent it.

Comment: My concern is that the server D could use IP addresses to determine which entries came from the same server

Comment: @EugeneStyer Good point. Maybe it would be possible that each server encrypts its batch of the data, and before D decrypts the aggregated (i.e., concatenated) it gets schuffeled in a way that D cannot determine?